# Which number or numbers could be in the middle?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

There are 27 positive whole numbers arranged from the smallest to the largest on a piece of paper. The first number is 1 and the last number is 25. The Sum of the all 27 numbers is 127, the sum of the first nine numbers is 21 and the sum of the last nine numbers is 65. Which number or numbers could be in the middle?

***I haven't solved this problem yet and I don't want the answer, I just want to get a clue or make sure that I'm on the right track.***

Here's what I know/think it's right:

- Some numbers should appear more than once and the amount of time they appear affects the range of numbers that could be in the middle like 1234 here 4 is the 4th number of 111234 here is 4 the 6th number.
- Sum of the 9 numbers/or the 9 positions in the middle is 41
- 25 cant appear more than once because if it appears more than once for example twice then 65-50= 15 so the sum of 8 numbers should be 15, and since we have already arranged the numbers that can make that sum (when we arranged the nine first numbers which gave us 21, 15<21)we cant make that sum again.

Comment: Working with the averages of the unknown numbers in each third, and therefore identifying some constraints on the middle nine reduces the possibilities. eg Eight numbers with total $20$ have an average between $2$ and $3$, so at least one of them has to be at least $3$ (and at least one has to be no larger than $2$). This is an alternative way of proceeding to looking at specific decompositions, and can be useful when you are dealing with larger groups of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The 9th number is at least $3$ because $1+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2<21$.
Similarly, the 19th number is at most $5$ because $6+6+6+6+6+6+6+6 + 25 >65$.

So the middle sum is of the form $3a+4b+5c=41$ with $a,b,c\ge 0$ and $a+b+c=9$.
This gives us $-a+c=41-4\cdot 9=5$ and in particular $c\ge 5$. Conclude.

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this problem, I don't understan how you solved the equation? Since there are 3 variables, don't you need 3 equations to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track.

HINT

Notice there is at least one number greater or equal to 5 in the middle.
But then, all 8 unknown numbers in the latest part are 5s.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen says that the 19th number is at most 5, how can it be a number(or at least) greater than 5 in the middle when the 19th number is at most 5?

Comment: I don't find a contradiction there. If the 19th is 5, then all numbers up to 26th are 5s. I was writing about the largest in the middle part, and pointing out a consequence to the latest part.